# Open cursor derivation logic

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, cursor, performance-testing

In an environment where online processing and batch processing is simultaneous, is there a way to devise the parameter open_cursors?

I am trying to look so that I can optimize our testing environment for open_cursor parameter. I have already checked the Oracle Performance Tuning guide but still I am unable to understand how to arrive to this number.

Will running load runner tests help me get to this number? Please let me know if any more info is needed to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually have a problem?  `open_cursors` is a limit on the number of cursors a single session can have open.  It is not a system-wide limit.  The proper value isn't influenced by load or what happens in some other session.

The default value is almost always more than sufficient for a properly written application.  If you have an application that has long-running sessions and cursor leaks, increasing the value may let you run longer before you start to encounter problems while you find and address the cursor leaks but if you have a leak you'll eventually run out no matter what your setting.  In the vast majority of cases, when people get an error related to `open_cursors`, the proper solution is to find and fix the bug that is leaking cursors rather than to change `open_cursors`.

Comment: Ya we do have a problem and the thing is we are accessing a third party proprietary system which is causing this issue regularly. On their suggestion we have tried to change the value multiple times because technically we do not understand their code. In the meantime they fix their code, is there some tool/methodology, other than increasing the value of open_cursors, which can help me analyse this problem better?

Comment: @ShashankVyas - If the third party is writing code that causes this bug, the third party almost certainly has one (or more) cursor leaks in their code.  If you can't fix the leak, no value of `open_cursors` is sufficient-- eventually the bad code will leak too many cursor handles and fail.  Increasing it will mean that it will take longer for the leak to cause a failure.  You could keep doubling the setting until it takes "acceptably long" to fail.  Or you could potentailly restart whatever process is leaking periodically so that it gets new sessions in which to leak resources.